# Java and enum [Novice]

Tags: java, enums, integer, int

I've got ome fail in java enums;

I'd like to have individual id number for specified enum created, but number seems to propagate to next enum object unfortunately.
Look at my case:

```
enum type{ int i;}
int id=1;
type t1.i=id;
id=2;
type t2.i=id;
```

But t1 has got t2 id number, but I want to have different id's.

Is there any solution in this case ?

I inform that it's simplification of my case and I can't change enum type to class.

Comment: Please post actual compiling code that you have a problem with. What you posted is not valid Java at all and as a result, it's not clear what you are asking about.

Comment: @whiteNinja is the use of an enum a requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums must define its own values (In some way you can look the enums as a  constant value):

```
public enum Type {
  TYPE1(1),
  TYPE2(2);

  int code;

  Type(int code){
    this.code = code; 
  }

  public int getCode(){
      return code;
  }
}
```

So you can use it like:

```
System.out.println(Type.TYPE1.getCode()); // Prints '1'
System.out.println(Type.TYPE2.getCode()); // Prints '2'
```

See more information about enums at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html